# More efficient 1d convolution in TensorFlow when filter size is 1

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I want a "convolutional" layer where the filter size is 1. I can achieve this using (option 1)

```
tflearn.layers.conv.conv_1d( input, n_output_channels, 1 )
```

or roll my own using (option 2)

```
tf.matmult( input, tf.tile( weights, [batch_size, 1, 1] ) )
```

where input has dimensions [batch,sequence,n_input_channels] and weights is [1,n_input_channels,n_output_channels].

The performance of these two options seems roughly equivalent, but I would guess both have inefficiencies: option 1 presumably has overhead from expecting a "real" convolutional, and the tile operation seems like it should be unnecessary in option 2. Is there a smarter way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using the GPU, the best is probably to stick to native cuDNN operations, in that case convolutions.

NVIDIA does not provide much details on their implementation, but I would be surprised that they do not have dedicated implementations for common, small sizes used in NN, including kernels with `1x1` spatial range. That most probably applies to other NN-specialized library as well such as Intel MKL-DNN on CPU.

Only when using generic, non-NN convolution libraries, or badly optimized ones, should your question apply. I don't think that is the case of tensorflow or any other major DL libaries and their dependencies out there. (Could be interesting to check in Eigen.)